Force readline to exit with signals
I am trying to get readline to exit when I press ctrl-c. I thought I could do this with rl_done but it is not working.
Upon pressing ctrl-c I am getting these debug statements:
start readline
setting rl_done to 1
so the signal is received and rl_done set to 1 but readline does not exit for some reason.
char    **continue_input(char **input, char *str)
{
    char    *line;
    char    *temp;

    ignore_signals();
    init_signals(CONTINUE_INPUT);
    printf("start readline%c-----------%c", 10, 10);fflush(stdout); //debug
    line = readline(str);
    printf("readline ended%c-----------%c", 10, 10);fflush(stdout); //debug
    if (rl_done == 1)
    {
        rl_done = 0;
        return (NULL);
    }
    if (!line)
    {
        ignore_signals();
        init_signals(FALSE);
        return (NULL);
    }
    temp = ft_strjoin(*input, "\n");
    free(*input);
    *input = ft_strjoin(temp, line);
    free(line);
    free(temp);
    if (!input)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    ignore_signals();
    init_signals(FALSE);
    return (input);
}




void    continue_input_signal_handler(int sig)
    {
        if (sig == SIGINT)
        {
            printf("setting rl_done to 1%c-----------%c", 10, 10);fflush(stdout); //debug
            rl_done = 1;
        }
        else if (sig == SIGTERM)
        {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }


Where did you get that exotic way to end your lines? printf("setting rl_done to 1%c-----------%c", 10, 10); What's wrong with \n? Even if you want to avoid any conversion to OS specific versions, you could still use \x0A

@Gerhardh it’s a vscode snippet and if I use in the json \n it’ll litteraly print \n

your post is confusing!, and as you've not posted a minimal reproducible example, here's a trivial example of terminating on ^C for illustration only ...
NB:(readline already handles this by default !

using info readline search for SIGINT will take you directly to the relevant text**

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

void trapC()
{
    puts("\n^c caught, terminating!");
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    char *buff;
    (void) signal(SIGINT,trapC);

    for(;;)
    {
        buff = readline( "\nenter stuff [^C to terminate] :");
        if ( buff )
                printf("you entered [%s]\n", buff );
        free(buff);
    }
    return(0);
}


